# What the ViewHandlingMethods means at @interface RootViewController (ViewHandlingMethods)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I downloaded the ScrollViewSuit source code from apple. I don't understand what the ViewHandlingMethods means at @interface RootViewController (ViewHandlingMethods) in RootViewController.m. Can anybody explain it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface RootViewController (ViewHandlingMethods)
```

Declares [class category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) - that allows to add methods to existing classes.

Declaring category in implementation file also makes possible to create 'compile-time' private methods - by not exposing their declaration in public class interface in header file. Class users will be able to call that methods anyway (as objective-c does not support real private methods), but as method declaration is not exposed in header file compiler will issue a warning about undeclared method.